# GridLayoutManager.scrollToPosition does not make any effect

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager, scroll-position

I have RecyclerView that uses GridLayoutManger in Fragment as follows:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//some code
mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
//some code
}
```

The RecyclerView is populated by adapter that loads data from CursorLoader,my issue is that I am trying to restore saved scroll position of GridLayoutManger to use when device rotates as follows:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mPosition=mGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    outState.putInt(GRID_LAYOUT_SCROLL_KEY,mPosition);
}


    @Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mPosition=savedInstanceState.getInt(GRID_LAYOUT_SCROLL_KEY);
        mGridLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(mPosition);
    }
}
```

but no thing changes when rotation happens as though scrollToPosition() method does not work at all.
I tried to put "mGridLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(mPosition);" inside "onLoadFinished" but I still get the same result! 
What is the proplem?

Comment: thanks for reply @pskink , I have tried this but still the same problem